# selecting where a cell has the same number as the id inside the string

Tags: mysql

here i have a view called commentsTableview that literally selects all of the data from the comments table which is called commentsTable, the replies column is a nested select statement.

```
+------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+
|idview|comments                             |replies|commentOn|
+------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+
|1     |this is a comment                    |0      |content24|
+------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+
|2     |this is a reply to that comment      |0      |comment1 |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+
|3     |this is another reply to that comment|0      |1        |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+
```

using this example if i run the query inside the view `(select count(*) from commentsTable where commentsTable.commentOn = idview) as replies` this will return 1 for the 1st cell because there is one commentedOn cell that is equal to its id.

however how would i select the cell that sais comment1 instead of just 1, keep in mind this is for a view so no variables can be set. im assuming group_concat is the function needed but ive been unable to get it right and concat this concat function doesnt work either `(select count(*) from commentsTable where commentsTable.commentOn = concat("comment", id) as replies`.

Comment: It appears that your table uses commentOn as a key to idview. If so, it should be the same type as idview, and both should be integers. But you could create a formula that eliminates "comment" and uses the remainder of the string as a key. Really bad design that will cause big performance hits as your table grows.

Comment: group_concat wouldn't be used in your where clause (actually a join clause), it would be used to combine the related comments.

Answer (score 0):

To get all of the rows as you describe and combine them into one row per idview, you might try:

```
SELECT
    a.`idview`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.`comments`)
FROM `commentsTable` a
JOIN `commentsTable` b
    ON a.`idview` = TRIM(b.`commentOn`) OR
    a.`idview` = TRIM(REPLACE(b.`commentOn`,"comment",""))
GROUP BY a.`idview`
```

Comment: it looks like youve joined two tables (table a and table b) and in my scenario there is only one table, this has me a little confused because i dont think your trying to join a table with its view.

Comment: The two tables are the same table. The join allows you to express a relationship between two rows (or more) related by different columns. I should have put your table name in the query. See the edited answer

Comment: this is good so far however, what if i wanted just the ones that say comment1 and not just any cell that has 1 or comment 1, what if i wanted a more precise search in the datatabase of all that say comment1. how would i do this, after this is answered i will accept the answer as it will have completely solved my problem.

Comment: additionally this puts it all in one string with or without the `GROUP BY` statement as if its ignoring it, would you be able to fix that bug?

Comment: Look at the ON clause. The first part (before the OR) selects those with just a number in commentOn, and the 2nd part selects those with 'comment' in commentOn. If you only want one matching comment, remove the GROUP_CONCAT. If there are rows with multiple matches, it will return multiple rows.